# update second table with the autoincremented id of the first table

Tags: php, mysql

This is my first post on the site. I'm a newbie with mysql and php so please pardon any mistakes and kindly point them out. 
I have a table to store hiring details:

**table_hiring**
hiringid  int(20) AUTOINCREMENT => (primary key);
hiringname varchar(80);
hiringdate bigint(20);
...
...

I have another table to store the tools and their hire prices which has:

**table_tools**
tool_id int(10)AUTOINCREMENT => (primary key);
tool_description varchar(100);
tool_price double;

Each hire request would be saved in the hiring table. My problem is that each hire request can have multiple tools(Its a ground hire. so the hirer can request a hurdles set, a shotput set and a javelin set and so on.). I was stumped with the problem of storing multiple values in a single field. I did some research and decided to have another table

**table_tool_hire**
tool_hire_id() => (primary key from table_hiring);
tool_id() => (primary key from table_tools);
tool_hire_date bigint(20);

The problem is that everytime there is a hire request, according to the hirer's request i need to populate table_hiring and table_tool_hire in one query and the hire Id needs to be the matching in both the tables.

How do I insert the values into table_hiring and simultaneously get the autoincremented id value of that hire to be updated into the table_tool_hire table?? Please help...Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For PHP, this is found with `mysql_insert_id()`.
For .NET, take a look at [this](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?38,98672,98868#msg-98868).

Comment: Thank you for the quick response Jeremy..I think mysql_insert_id() should solve my problem..will post again after trying it out..You just made my life a whole lot easier... :D

Comment: worked like a charm!!! The function should be called right after the query execution though...Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

please take a look to this forum,

[Get all insert ids in a transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10755334/get-all-insert-ids-in-a-transaction/10755486#10755486)

you can use variables an store there the last insert id,

```
INSERT INTO messages(`message`) VALUES ('message1');
@message1:=last_insert_id();
INSERT INTO messages_tags(`message_id`, `tags`) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'tagfoo1');
@message2:=last_insert_id();
```

if you make

```
select @message1;
```

the result would be 1234, so you have

```
@message1 => 1234
@message2 => 1235
```